# How to detect if environment is development or production with Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I detect if my server environment is development or production with Firebase Cloud Functions?

I need something like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

   // DO STUFF SPECIFIC TO DEV ENVIRONMENT

}
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

   // DO STUFF SPECIFIC TO PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT

}
```

Answer (score 67):

### process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR

At **process.env**, on firebase functions projects, there is a boolean variable called **FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR**, which indicates if the process is running on an emulator or on server.

this is enough to determine if environment is dev or production.

```js
process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === true
```

Obs: In some environments the variable might be a String **'true'** instead of Boolean **true**

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the question asked about **server** environment, not the local emulator.  This answer is only applicable for detecting when using the emulator is being used locally.  It would not help in determining which project is being used.  The emulator has no way of knowing if the project in use is designated for development or production, or something else.  The emulator even really care about which project you want to use, so it's still possible to make a mistake that affects the project in an undesirable way.

Comment: @DougStevenson If you have different projects for different environments then you can easily determine if it's a staging, production environment by checking `process.env['GCLOUD_PROJECT']`, which will return the name of the project. Using the name you can determine in which environment the functions are running.

Answer (score 40):

## you can rely on `process.env`

as of July 28, 2020 and package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
},
```

if you start your app with firebase

#### `firebase emulators:start`

then`process.env` will have properties like

```
"FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR": "true",
"FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST": "0.0.0.0:5002",
"PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST": "localhost:8085"
"FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST": "0.0.0.0:9099"
```

if you start your app with firebase

#### `firebase emulators:start --only functions`

then`process.env` will have properties like

```
"FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR": "true",
```

#### USECASE

based on process.env you can write firebase.function to prepopulate your firestore emulator (not production firestore)!

#### code sample

```
export const prepopulateFirestoreEmulator = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    if (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR && process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST) {
      // TODO: prepopulate firestore emulator from 'yourproject/src/sample_data.json
      response.send('Prepopulated firestore with sample_data.json!');
    } else {
      response.send(
        "Do not populate production firestore with sample_data.json"
      );
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

All Google Cloud projects are just projects, except for how you designate their purpose.  Since there is no way for Cloud Functions to know the difference between dev and prod, you need to examine the name of the project, since that's the only thing that changes in the environment.  Use `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT` from the [automatically populated env vars](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables).

It seems that other answers here are making the assumption that this question is asking about local development, which it is not.  It's easy to detect if code is running in the emulator, but that does not help you determine if the underlying project is meant for development or production (or some other purpose).  It's still very possible for some code running in the emulator to have an unwanted effect only the underlying project, which would be bad for a project designated as production.  It's strongly advised to run and isolate different projects for different deployments so changes in one do not affect the other.

Comment: Hmmm the project name is the same for localhost fyi

Comment: @JimmyKane If you want to distinguish between running on Cloud Functions or running in the local emulator, that is a different issue. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ZVGlmFsASW4

Comment: Wouldn't the best way be to create an environment variable in Firebase such as `isProd` and set it to the correct boolean value in each environment?

Comment: @DougStevenson it is said [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#environment_variables_set_automatically) that `GCLOUD_PROJECT` is now deprecated. Any idea what to use?