# can I make a Cloud Function that only for local Firebase Emulators?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I need to make a function that will be used only for Firebase emulator. I need to perform some actions to my Firestore emulators, to populate Firestore emulators using dummy data.

I write this code in my `index.ts`

```
exports.onlyForFirebaseSimulator = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  
  
});
```

I want to make this function available when I run `firebase emulators:start` , but it will not be deployed to production when I run `firebase deploy`.

I have to comment it out manually before deployment. I don't want to manually set it, because it is error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find the answer.

I am using [group functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#group_functions) to organize multiple functions in my `index.ts` , I suggest you to read it first, otherwise you will be confused to read my `index.ts` . I am using Typescript/ES6, but the concept will be the same

for 'normal' deployment, in `index.ts` will be like this

```
// Firestore triggers
export * as users from "./firestore/triggers/users/users_triggers";
export * as users_attendedEvents from "./firestore/triggers/users/attendedEvents/attended_events_triggers";
export * as users_followers from "./firestore/triggers/users/followers/followers_triggers";

// Firebase Authentication triggers
export * as auth from "./firebase_authentication/triggers/firebase_auth_triggers";
```

and now I want to add functions that will not be deployed on production (when I run `firebase deploy` ) but will be available when emulators is running (when I run firebase emulators:start)

to detect whether the emulators is running or not, we can check its  environment variable, `process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR` will be true. [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63127747/9605341) for more info

so my full `index.ts` will be like this

```
// Firestore triggers
export * as users from "./firestore/triggers/users/users_triggers";
export * as users_attendedEvents from "./firestore/triggers/users/attendedEvents/attended_events_triggers";
export * as users_followers from "./firestore/triggers/users/followers/followers_triggers";
    
// Firebase Authentication triggers
export * as auth from "./firebase_authentication/triggers/firebase_auth_triggers";

// The code below will be exported only if emulators are running, to avoid deployment to production server
const isRunningOnEmulator = (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR && process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST);
import * as emulator_functions from "./utilities/emulators/http_triggers/for_testing_via_firestore_emulators";
export const forEmulator = isRunningOnEmulator ? emulator_functions : undefined;
```

Comment: basically I combine the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250699/how-to-make-some-lines-in-index-ts-not-executed/67250832#67250832 and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185426/how-to-detect-if-environment-is-development-or-production-with-firebase-cloud-fu/63127747#63127747

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying with the [Firebase CLI deploy command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets#deploy-target-commands) you could select only the functions to deploy to production by specifying the --only flag as explained on the relevant sections of the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#deploy_functions): e.g. if you have three functions named addMessage, makeUppercase, and onlyForFirebaseSimulator running the following command:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:addMessage,functions:makeUppercase
```

will not deploy your onlyForFirebaseSimulator to production.