# how to make some lines in index.ts not executed?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

so in my `index.ts` I initially have code like this

```
export * as users from "./firestore/triggers/users/users_triggers";
export * as auth from "./firebase_authentication/triggers/firebase_auth_triggers";
```

and then I have another `export` in my `index.ts`, but I want this export only executed if it meets some criteria. so in my `index.ts` will be like this

```
export * as users from "./firestore/triggers/users/users_triggers";
export * as auth from "./firebase_authentication/triggers/firebase_auth_triggers";

const meetSomeCriteria = true;
if (meetSomeCriteria) return;

// if it meets some criteria, then I expect the code below won't be triggered
export * as utilities from "./utilities/emulators/http_triggers/for_testing_via_firestore_emulators";
```

but I will have error if I have return like that
[image]

so how to make some lines in index.ts not executed?

those export utilities is actually some functions that I will be used only for Firebase Emulators. I want to avoid those functions to be deployed in production

Comment: how would the consumers know if utilities is a thing they can import or not? Is it Schrodinger's utilities?

Comment: you can put this code in a function and then you write ```if(meetSomeCriteria) function()```. Or you could put the code above in a function and call it, in the function you are able to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no conditional imports or exports in typescript. Ie you cannot write something like

```
if (acondition)
  import x from "module"
```

But you can workaround it like this

```
import * as utilimport from "./your/module";

export const utilities = meetSomeCriteria
   ? utilimport 
   : undefined
   ;
```